# running the ZREVRANGEBYSCORE in node redis always gets wrong

Tags: redis, node-redis

I am working on the latest redis with node.js, however running the ZREVRANGEBYSCORE command puzzles me.

Here are the errors I got but none of them worked out.

```
TypeError: redisClient.ZREVRANGEBYSCORE is not a function
TypeError: redisClient.zrevRangeByScore is not a function 
TypeError: redisClient.zrevrangebyscore is not a function
```

any idea how to get it right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ZREVRANGEBYSCORE](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore/) is deprecated in Redis as a version 6.2 and Node Redis no longer implements it. [ZRANGE](https://redis.io/commands/zrange/) does All The Things™️ now.

Here's how to invoke ZRANGE to duplicate what ZREVRANGEBYSCORE would do for you:

```js
await client.zRange('key', 0, 5, {
  BY: 'SCORE',
  REV: true,
}
```

Details like this aren't well documented for Node Redis so when I run into them, I look at the [unit tests](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/master/packages/client/lib/commands) to figure them out. Not saying you should have looked there, just helping to teach you to fish.

Comment: thanks, I look at the documentation, ZRANGE_WITHSCORES is also an extra command based on zrange to return the value with score.